# Parallel inductors in boost converter topology

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inductor, boost

I need to design a boost converter using a 750uH boost inductor after calculations. But I just have 3 inductors each 2.2mH.
Can I put these 3 inductors in parallel?
If no why? What is the drawback and inconvenient?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, but why? Is it a one off for a bench test? Go for it! Mass production? Ill advised.

Comment: Yes for testing

Comment: Then no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Can I put these 3 inductors in parallel?*

Depending on the physical type of inductor and their proximity to each other, you may get unwanted effects. For instance, if they are not particularly well-shielded from each other and, you mount them quite close to each other, cross-coupling of magnetic fields can mean that the net inductance is much closer to the original 2200 μH than the desired 750 μH.

But, it can be more problematic if it's unclear how the inductors are wound because two of them could be producing opposing fluxes and then, the net inductance might be closer to zero than you bargained for. As always, the devil is in the details.

These types can be particularly problematic if not spaced sufficiently far away from each other: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fxppower.en.made-in-china.com%2Fproduct%2FLvImHcxUORhX%2FChina-Top-Quality-Leaded-Power-Pin-Inductors-and-Power-Choke-Coils-with-Ferrite-Drum-Core.html&psig=AOvVaw3yIsUl81Sa9HiFSG70ftyH&ust=1644090187966000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCOCBz6_n5vUCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAQ).

If the inductors are "shielded" (like below) there shouldn't be any significant problems: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.haloelectronics.com%2Fpdf%2Fsmd-shielded-drumcore.pdf&psig=AOvVaw0tRDpoHyMkm7lpnXY5agFn&ust=1644090376633000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCNC44ono5vUCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAP).

Comment: Thanks for this interesting comment. My inductors are drum core (unshielded). Which distance should I respect between each?

Comment: How long is a piece of string @Teddol - you might experiment a bit to see what happens but, other than clear and explicit information in the inductor data sheets, it's guesswork. They might be OK at 3 mm distance or, they might need 10 mm separation. I will also add this; drum inductors are usually not at all recommended for switching converters that require high performance (irrespective of paralleling them) and, if they have more than a few hundred milliohms resistance you may be disappointed in the result. Of course, you haven't revealed the circuit nor the data sheets so it's guesswork.

Comment: I can separate them from 10mm to 50mm or more... I just want it work fine. Inductor model: AIRD-02-222K

Comment: OK, but, be aware that having such gaps between wound components and the boost converter's circuitry can lead to other problems on emissions, ringing and output voltage ripple.

Comment: You're right. It's not so easy finally...

Answer (score 0):

> Can I put these 3 inductors in parallel?

Yes, x3 2.2mH inductors in parallel will give you 730uH which is close to 750uH so if 730uH works for the boost converter then you should be able at least try it. But there is one more thing to consider:

The 2.2mH inductors will have series resistance, and this resistance will also change when you put them in parallel. You could add them together using complex impedances. The ESR (equivalent series resistance) should go down if you put inductors in parallel.